# Loading multiple images in sequence on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm working on an application that talks home to a server and retrieves some data with image URL's embedded in it.  I want to display those images on the view, and am getting them like so:

```
UIImageView *ivAvatar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.avatarUrl]]]];
[self.view addSubview:ivAvatar];
[ivAvatar release];
```

However, whenever data is retrieved (for example, on startup of the application), there is a delay between the retrieval of the data and the user being able to interact with the application due to the blocking nature of `dataWithContentsofURL`.

What is the proper way to do "Asynchronous" downloading of images?  I need the UI to be responsive and load all other data that is retrieved, but load the images while allowing the UI to be responsive.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

NSURL, NSURLRequest, and NSURLConnection.

Comment: Could you direct me to an example of how these work together?